# JSON - Join Values From Array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

How can I combine the two values of key `text` and return the key with "\n" in between? I would like the output to show as the following.

```
{ "text": "Hi ! Nice to meet you !\nMy name is Robot." }
```

Here is the JSON structure:

```
{
"output": {
  "log_messages": [],
  "text": [
    "Hi ! Nice to meet you !",
    "My name is Robot."
  ],
  "nodes_visited": [
    "Hello"
  ]
}
```

I figured out how to return the two keys but do not know what to do to return them as one string. Thanks!

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Parsing JSON? Accessing attributes in the resulting dictionary? Returning?

Comment: You might not notice it because of the tabbing, but you are missing a closing `}` from that JSON example (in case it's not just a copy/paste error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    obj = json.load(f)

output = {'text': '\n'.join(obj['output']['text'])}
print output
#    {'text': 'Hi ! Nice to meet you !\nMy name is Robot.'}
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU (It says I have to wait 8 minutes to accept an answer)

Comment: happy to help!!

Comment: that's invalid JSON

Comment: I know. It is not the full thing.How would I do it though.

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the actual JSON because the structure of the first two is different than the third. Is that not the actual case?

Comment: They are suppose to be different.

Comment: This is a much more involved task, you should ask a new question and I can help you there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149654/discussion-between-brendan-and-wpercy).